# Creating an alias that uses renamer with a regular expression

Tags: node.js, bash, alias, zsh

`renamer --regex --find '(^..).*' --replace '$1.tex' *`

is the expression that i want to use.
but for the life of me i can't figure out how i would have to create this as an alias/ bash / zsh script.

`alias renamer_help="renamer --help"`

works but
when i do thse same with the expression above.
my shell i telling me that 

`.zshrc:119: renamer --regex --find '(^..).*' --replace '$1.tex' * not found`

I basically spend the last couple of hours trying different escape sequence but nothing worked :/

Comment: Consider also including the code that gives errors, and not just the error message itself.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are like aliases but more robust and don't require escaping:

```
myrenamer() {
  renamer --regex --find '(^..).*' --replace '$1.tex' *
}
```

Run with `myrenamer` as you would with an alias.